# commas in English speech

Tags: grammar, commas, speech, linguistics

I know commas can make a big difference in the meaning and interpretation of sentences. However, in speech, when we speak out loud, how does the listener interpret sentences if there is no punctuation. Especially if someone tends to speak in a halting manner, like myself, because I am not very good at English.
For example, I said out loud, "A wishful thought followed by action.....it is a good thing....a wise thing.....if a person believes he can manifest his destiny." How is the listener to know that I meant that the "if a person believes he can manifest his destiny" conditional to apply to everything said before it versus just "a wise thing."

Comment: A person who is not very good at English is best avoiding expressions like  'manifest his destiny' and perhaps even 'wishful thought' which will puzzle many native speakers.

Comment: No, a comma does not represent a pause in speech. There are rarely pauses in speech. We've been trained to say they're pauses, but they never show us speech spectrograms in grammar school so we don't know that speech is continuous. The illusion of spaces in writing is persuasive. What commas represent is one of several intonation contours that start on one syllable and end one or two farther on; normally the tone pattern is `mid-low-high-mid`, as in counting: _seventy-six, seventy-seven, seventy-eight, ..._. When we hear it, we write it; when we don't hear it, we don't write it.

Answer (score 0):

The question puts the cart before the horse. A major function of punctuation in the written language in English is to indicate how a sentence is **spoken** — where, and how long, pauses are, which themselves indicate the association of words and hence the meaning of the sentence.

If the spoken language is poor in this respect, the meaning is obscure, and any textual ‘improvement’ is mere speculation. One should remember that language developed long before writing.